# Getting a distinct list of values from a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'value': 'apple', 'blah': 2}, 
 {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 3} , 
 {'value': 'banana', 'blah': 4}]
```

I want distinct data on the basis of one field  for eg 'value' so I want this output **['apple', 'banana']**

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want distinct values from only one key? I don't see why 2, 3, 4 wouldn't be included in the distinct values otherwise.

Comment: I’d suggest looking into the `set` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to use this piece of code?

```
list(set(element.get('value') for element in input_collection))
```

---

Or even it would be good to apply suggestion of @csjh

```
list(set(element['value'] for element in input_collection if 'value' in element))
```

Comment: Instead of using .get() I think `element['value'] for element in input_collection if 'value' in element` or similar would be better, otherwise there might be a None in there

Answer (score 1):

We could try set comprehension (added if condition in case `'value'` key doesn't exist, thanks @0x263A):

```
out = list({d['value'] for d in lst if 'value' in d})
```

If order is important, we can also use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
out = list(dict.fromkeys([d['value'] for d in lst if 'value' in d]).keys())
```

Output:

```
['apple', 'banana']
```

Comment: This will cause a KeyError if `value` isn't in d, but is easily fixable by adding `if 'value' in d` to the comprehension.

Comment: @0x263A great suggestion. Thanks